# Trying to add string starting from the right going to the left in a specific area

Tags: javascript, string, math, numbers

I've been trying to figure out how to add period as a string in a certain place, here's the code

```js
function fixBalance(amount){
  if(amount <= 99999999){
    var amt = "0." + amount.toString().padStart(8, "0");
    return Number(amt);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(fixBalance(1));
console.log(fixBalance(1000));
console.log(fixBalance(10000000));
console.log(fixBalance(1000000000));
```

Basically, there are 8 spaces to the right of the 0

After it passes 8 numbers, I want numbers to keep going past the period

For example:

`1 = 0.00000001`

`1000 = 0.00001000 or 0.00001`

`10000000 = 0.10000000 or 0.1`

`100001000 = 0.100001000`

`1000000001 = 10.00000001`

`1010000000 = 10.10000000`

`10100000000 = 101.00000000`

If I were to put in 1000000000, it should be 10.00000000 or 10 as a numerical number

Trying to figure out how to do that with the else statement

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about determining the integer and decimal parts separately before composing them?

```js
function fixBalance(amount){
  const divisor = 100_000_000;
  const integer = Math.floor(amount / divisor);
  const decimal = amount % divisor;
  
  return integer.toString() + "." + decimal.toString().padStart(8, "0");
}

console.log(fixBalance(1));
console.log(fixBalance(1000));
console.log(fixBalance(10000000));
console.log(fixBalance(1000000000));
```

Comment: Very sorry about accepting this answer late, this works perfectly, thank you! :)